# regex to grep multiple line data

Tags: java, regex

## I have a large text data, from that I am able to reach specific portion. Specific portion is shown below:

```
Caption = "Universal Plug and Play Device Host"
   CheckPoint = 0
   CreationClassName = "Win32_Service"
   Description = "Provides support to host Universal Plug and Play devices."
   DesktopInteract = FALSE
   DisplayName = "Universal Plug and Play Device Host"
   ErrorControl = "Normal"
   ExitCode = 1077
   Name = "upnphost"
   PathName = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\svchost.exe -k LocalService"
   ProcessId = 0
   ServiceSpecificExitCode = 0
   ServiceType = "Share Process"
   Started = FALSE
   StartMode = "Disabled"
   StartName = "NT AUTHORITY\\LocalService"
   State = "Stopped"
   Status = "OK"
   SystemCreationClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem"
   SystemName = "KYAKKALA-WXP"
   TagId = 0
   WaitHint = 0
```

I need to separate the text and store into groups.

I tried with following regex:

```
String REGEX ="(Caption)\\s=.*?(VMware USB.*)\"\\;\\n((?:(\\w+)\\s+=\\s+(.*)\\n)   {1,21}?)";
```

By applying the regex, i m getting in gp1 "caption", gp2 "vmware usb arbitration      service", gp3 "waithint" and in gp4 "0".
i need to fetch all the data for 21 lines
but its fetching only for first and last line.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to read this with `java.util.Properties` ?

Comment: I have to do in the same way as shown and data need to be fetched in single regex. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't match an arbitrary number of groups with one regex.
You should give up Multiline matching, and use a global modifier to use your regex on each line. Then you can loop through the results.

... or do as Deepak Bala said and use properties.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the group numbers get overwritten inside a `*`, `+` or `{...}` statement. So, when doing something like `(?:(...))*`, group 1 will get overwritten for every new match, so, when printing group 1, you'll only see the last match.

However you can do something like: (changed according to your needs)

```
String str = "Caption = \"Universal Plug and Play Device Host\"\n"+
  "  CheckPoint = 0\n"+
  "  CreationClassName = \"Win32_Service\"\n"+
  "  Description = \"Provides support to host Universal Plug and Play devices\"";

String regex = "(?:^|\n)\\s*(\\w*)\\s*=\\s*(.*?)(?=\r?\n|$)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println("Name = " + m.group(1));
   System.out.println("Value = " + m.group(2));
}
```

Which will print:

```
Name = Caption
Value = "Universal Plug and Play Device Host"
Name = CheckPoint
Value = 0
Name = CreationClassName
Value = "Win32_Service"
Name = Description
Value = "Provides support to host Universal Plug and Play devices"
```